# Is it possible to allocate memory dynamically to the global variable or static variable?

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
int* arr = new int[10];
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> 01234

I thought global variable cannot be allocated dynamically, because global(and static) variable is initialized before running program and the dynamic allocation occurs in running time. But the code works well!!  I cannot understand why the code works..

Comment: Is this C++ or C? You're using `new` to allocate memory, but you've tagged it [c].

Comment: I'm sorry. It's C++

Comment: In that case you either likely want to use the "iostream" header or "cstdio" in which case `printf` would be `std::printf`.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but from your question you *might* be confused about stack/heap variables. When you have something like, `int * ptr = new int[3]`, it's important to recall that `ptr` exists ***on the stack***, it's given a number by the OS as to the memory it owns. The memory it owns is on the heap, but the pointer itself (in this case) is not.

Answer (score 1):

C++ allows this, while C does not.

Since you are using `new` to allocate memory, you likely have accidentally used a c++ compiler, rather than a c compiler.

Comment: By c++ compiler, the global variable is allocated in Heap before running program?

Comment: The call to new is run before `main()` is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you’re actually referencing C++, the standard says that static and global variables must live for the entire program execution. This **does not** mean they have to be initialized at compile time although that is one way to do it unless you dynamically allocate them.

In general this is bad practice however because what happens when you try to delete/free the memory before the program ends?

Comment: One could easily simplify this to "global variables are bad practice" and it would still be good advice.

Comment: @Elliot this is true, but there are often good reasons to free memory at some point *before* the program ends and not just *at* the end.